# Unable to DOS commands using Power shell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

In my process document I run below mentioned commands from command prompt and it works fine from command prompt but it does not work when I run these commands from Power Shell.

c:\temp\sig.csv sig.csv has input file.
I want this command to be executed silently and it takes input from sig.csv file located in temp folder.

Below is the link which I am following but using powershell.

https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/documentation/40/endpoint/endpoint-admin-guide/manage-traps-in-a-vdi-environment/configure-the-master-policy/traps-vdi-tool-cli.html

Dos Command:

```
TrapsVdiTool -i:c:\temp\sig.csv -e:192.168.70.100 -ssl -to:1
```

I run it using cmd.exe also tried executing using using &

```
& TrapsVdiTool -i:c:\temp\sig.csv -e:192.168.70.100 -ssl -to:1
cmd.exe /c "TrapsVdiTool -i:c:\temp\sig.csv -e:192.168.70.100 -ssl -to:1"
```

Comment: What does “does not work” mean? Errors?

Comment: I am getting below error.
Invalid format of command line parameter -i:C:\temp\sig.csv'. Aborting.

Comment: Anyone there who can help me ?
I am getting below error following error "Invalid format of command line parameter -i:C:\temp\sig.csv'. Aborting"

Comment: Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Powershell console it should run this way:

```
& TrapsVdiTool '-i:c:\temp\sig.csv' '-e:192.168.70.100' '-ssl' '-to:1'
```

[Powershell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)